# Swift call a method after 2 bool didset call

Tags: swift, property-observer

I have 2 bool with a didset method. Inside both didset it called a same method. So I want to call a method after that 2 bool did sets called

```
var canDo: Bool {
    didSet {
        reload()
    }
}

var isView: Bool {
    didSet {
        reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi user, I'm not sure if I correctly understand your problem. Do you want to call a method after both bools have been changed, or either have been changed?

Comment: Can you add a code snippet so that it is easier to understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: var canDo: Bool {
    didSet {
        reload()
    }
}

var isView: Bool {
    didSet {
        reload()
    }
} @axel

Comment: @MacUserT both values set

Comment: Set as in true? if both are true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var canDo: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isView{
            reload()
        }

    }
}

var isView: Bool {
    didSet {
        if canDo{
            reload()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a new function to handle the logic for when to call `reload()` rather than having the logic in both `didSet`'s. This way if new logic needs to be added it can be added in one place:

```
var canDo: Bool {
    didSet { maybeReload() }
}

var isView: Bool {
    didSet { maybeReload() }
}

private func maybeReload() {
    guard
        canDo,
        isView
        else { return }

    reload()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

We can achieve this with the help of `Optionals`

Now when update your code like

```
var canDo: Bool? {
    didSet {
        if isView != nil {
         reload()
        }
    }
}

var isView: Bool? {
    didSet {
        if canDo != nil {
         reload()
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you meant set as in `true` then simply ignore the above and add

```
var canDo: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isView {
         reload()
        }
    }
}

var isView: Bool {
    didSet {
        if canDo {
         reload()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any other way Without introduce new boolean

Comment: @user1684899 yes we can use `Optional` too just edited the answer to show case its use.